# Javascript startpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there any way to make my browser tell me what is the first JavaScript that is executed when I click on for instance a div.

Let me break it down:

**Code example:**

```
<div id='hello'> Hi There </div>
jQuery('hello').bind('click', function() { alert('hello') });
```

The code above will naturally display hello when I click on it. But is there a way to make firebug or console in Chrome to automatically break on the first very first JavaScript call without explicit set the break point.

In a complex JavaScript web pages there is a lot of binds but takes hours to find what is the actual code behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all events of an element with `console.log($(element).data("events"));`

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm following the question you have this scenario:

```
jQuery('#hello') //function call 1
    .bind('click', function(){ function call 2
        alert('hello');
    });
```

One method to do this would be to override the function you want to test. You cache the actual function, overwrite it with yours to do debugging in, then execute your cache with the original arguments.

```
(function(){
    var _jquery = jQuery;
    jQuery = function(){
        console.log('debug');
        _jquery(arguments);
    }
})();
```